# AMD switchable graphics are not working OR I don't know how to make them work

Tags: windows-8, drivers, switchable-graphics

I don't know if this is the right place for this question, but I'll give it a shot.
I have a **Dell Inspiron 17R 5721**. It's supposed to be using switchable graphics. It has an **Intel HD 4000** and a **Radeon HD 8730M** and I'm using windows 8.

My problem is this, I Installed the drivers that dell gives me but I don't see the AMD graphics card ANYWHERE ( I do see it in device manager but not anywhere else to select and play a game using AMD). I installed the latest drivers from AMD and same thing, I can't run a game with AMD graphics card. I change the applications preferences in the **Catalyst control center** but even after that, games don't give me the option to select the AMD card, they list only the **Intel HD 4000**.

Can someone tell me what I have to do to make this work?

**-------------------**

After looking around and messing with stuff. I think.... I THINK that you don't 
really get the option to select a graphics card. Switchable graphics is all about
switching automatically depending on application's needs. Cause when I uninstalled
AMD's drivers or actually (screwed up lol) games were playing much worse. When I re-installed them, games went back to being good looking. So even if a game sees only the **Intel HD 4000** graphics card windows or AMD's drivers will switch to the **AMD Readeon** graphics card automatically. I hope someone can verify this. Cause seriously I don't think  you get to play skyrim with High graphics settings or even ultra with the **Intel HD** Graphics card.

**-------------------**

Comment: You might want to grab the latest drivers from AMD's website and see if they work better for you. I believe the drivers for your card can be found at http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/mobile?os=Windows%208%20-%2064 for Windows 8 x64. Let us know how that goes!

Comment: You'll have to explicitly select the dedicated graphics card via a BIOS setting. I'm pretty sure this can't be done within the Windows environment.

Comment: Then what's the point of switchable graphics if I have to set it up from bios? I don't think what you're saying is reasonable or the  right solution.